# How to add CSS class to Leaflet Control

Tags: leaflet

I wish to assign CSS classes to a leaflet control.
The control works fine, but I wish to style it.

```
var search = L.Control.geocoder({
    collapsed:false, placeholder:"Search Criteria", position:'topright'
});
search.setStyle({className: 'form-control'});
search.addTo(map);
```

The error from this is
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: search.setStyle is not a function

Obviously, setStyle is not a function of the search object.
How do I set a custom style for this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the html/DOM container of the control with `search.getContainer()` and then you can add a css class.

```
L.DomUtil.addClass(search.getContainer(),'form-control')
```