# How to format the text and font color or background in a React-Leaflet Overlay component

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using the react-leaflet library and am using the LayersControl components.  I have numerous categories where I would like to format the text and color of the font to match the color of the  that is shown when the checkbox is checked.  So if TEST shows red points, I would like the text on the checkbox to be red.  I have tried passing in styles to both the LayersControl and Overlay, but have not had any luck so far.

```
<LayersControl position="topright" >
  <LayersControl.Overlay name="TEST" checked={true} >
     <WMSTileLayer></WMSTileLayer>
  </LayersControl.Overlay>
  <LayersControl.Overlay name="TEST2" checked={true} >
     <WMSTileLayer></WMSTileLayer>
  </LayersControl.Overlay>
</LayersControl>
```

Comment: You'll have to dig into the underlying leaflet components and manipulate their classnames manually. That is discussed in [How to add CSS class to Leaflet Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821258/how-to-add-css-class-to-leaflet-control).  It is not as simple as adding className or style to the LayersControl.Overlay component, unfortunately.  Even vanilla leaflet doesn't have a great way to do this in a simple fashion AFAIK